# Misleading information in the Codex, how do they get away with it?

Tags: template-tags, codex

I'm new to WordPress Development but I've programmed in PHP for a couple of years.

My understanding is that the Codex pages are as close to authoritative information on WordPress that you're going to get and that it is the place to look to when you want to learn WordPress development.

Some information is good but take for instance this section "Boolean Template Tags" on the introductory page about template tags: https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Template_Tags#Boolean_Template_Tags

The documentation writer claims that a string passed into the wp_list_cats function can have multiple values if they are 'connected together with boolean math techniques'. That's bogus, && is logical AND syntax in most programming languages and & is bitwise but it doesn't have anything to do with the string right, it's just for parsing purposes and is identical to a query string.

For me it's not a biggie because I know better but thousands of beginners are mislead and presented with more complex information than need be.

Are there no editors that have to check information before it gets posted?

Comment: Why are you asking here? Bring that up in https://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback Create a wordpress.org account and login and edit the page https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Template_Tags#Boolean_Template_Tags

Comment: show me a piece of software where the documentation is not lagging behind the development and i'll print out and eat all the code i've ever written, lol

Comment: There are bound to be mistakes in documents that are editable by anybody. It's a wiki, go ahead and change it if you see anything that's incorrect :-). WordPress changes all the time, and so does/should its supporting documentation.

Comment: Alright then I might create my own documentation site for wordpress then. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`wp_list_cats()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_cats/) was already depreciated in version 2.1, which a couple of millenia ago. You should not be using functions which is marked depreciated. In all probability, the info regarding the specific function is almost always wrong as it is long time outdated. You should really develop with [debug set to true](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). If this was the case, you should have seen the depreciation notice.

Regarding the codex and its documentation I can tell you that everyone with a valid wordpress.org account can edit/add/remove info from the codex. The codex is not upheld or maintained by the core developers, neither by a set team of experts. This does lead to incorrect info being added or even outdated info not being updated to the current version of WordPress.

It is really unfortunate that there are so much incorrect data in the codex, I can tell you that there are some pages in the codex which is absolute crap and completely wrong. Unfortunately, there isn't many experts that takes part in maintaining the codex, and most updates are done by people that are not well versed in WordPress and its practices.

As with the SE stack sites, every user on wordpress.org are there as-and-when they have spare time, and it is out of free will to help others or update the codex. No one is getting paid for any type of service rendered on these sites.

The codex still stays a great resource for info, regardless of the some technical discrepancies in its info. It still however stays your own responsibility to cross reference documentation with the actual source code. The value of core source code can never be understated. And always remember, http://wordpress.stackexhange.com always stays a great resource of info, and is in most cases more correct that the codex.

One last request, if you feel confident that your info is correct, and you see something very wrong in the codex, feel free to correct that info. Just remember, whatever you update, WordPress is still stuck at PHP 5.2.voetsek, so all syntax that you use should be PHP 5.2 compatible